# Negate @available in Swift

Tags: swift

iOS 13 brings in some handy extensions that I have quite a while now; I'd like to retain my code for iOS 11 and 12 and use built-in for iOS 13:

```
extension CIImage {
    // if iOS 13 not available
    open class var black: CIImage { return CIImage(color: .black) }
}
```

Comment: `@available(iOS, obsoleted:13.0)` works if the deployment target is 13.0